# Do Facebook tab pages now require app review?

Tags: facebook, tabpage

I've created and installed dozens of tab pages, but this latest one is having issues and I'm seeing a request for review that I haven't seen before. Is Facebook requiring review for tab pages now? Can anyone confirm this?

[image: Facebook review]

Comment: No, the pure page tab functionality does not require review. But you have added both Facebook Login and App Center in the products section, so you probably have items that require review in there.

Comment: Yep, it looks like because the App Center is there it's expecting a game. Thanks.